# Flashbuilder 4.5.1 Reading from SQLite DB, cannot display info as text

Tags: android, apache-flex, sqlite, flash-builder, data-formats

About me: 
I am just starting out. I know there has to be a simple way to do this, but after a week I am still stumped.
What it is: 
I have made an app to replace a very long written procedure. I would like to have text input boxes populated with the previous given answer for the test they are running.
Problem:
I can get the correct info from the DB; however I cannot put it in the text input field.
The box just displays: [object Object]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is sample code for the Settings.mxml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Settings" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Label id="DB_Name_Label" left="10" top="10" width="150" height="50" fontSize="28"
             text="DB Name" textAlign="right" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:TextInput id="DB_Name_Input" left="170" top="10" width="300" height="50" fontSize="32"/>

    <s:Label id="Test_Title" left="10" top="70" width="150" height="50" fontSize="28"
             text="Test Title" textAlign="right" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:TextInput id="Test_Title_Input" left="170" top="70" width="300" height="50" fontSize="32"/>

    <s:Button id="Equipment_Button" left="10" right="10" top="130" height="50"
              label="Save, then next Page" click="EquipmentButtonClick()"/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;     

            protected var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;

            public function add_info_to_DB(tableName:String, valueToBeSaved:String):void
            {
                sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
                sqlConnection.open(File.userDirectory.resolvePath(DB_Name_Input.text+".db"));
                var add2db:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                add2db.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                add2db.text = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, answer TEXT)");
                add2db.execute();

                add2db.text = "INSERT INTO "+tableName+" (answer) VALUES (?)";
                add2db.parameters[0] = valueToBeSaved;
                add2db.execute();
            }

            [bindable] public var testdata:Object= new Object();

            protected function EquipmentButtonClick():void
            {   
                add_info_to_DB("Test_Title",Test_Title_Input.text);         
                navigator.pushView(views.ReadfromDB, testdata);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

Here is code for the ReadfromDB.mxml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Reading" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Label id="DB_to_Read_Label" left="10" top="10" width="150" height="50" fontSize="28"
             text="DB to Read" textAlign="right" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:TextInput id="DB_to_Read" left="170" top="10" width="300" height="50" fontSize="32"/>

    <s:Label id="Test_Title" left="10" top="70" width="150" height="50" fontSize="28"
             text="Test Title" textAlign="right" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:TextInput id="Test_Title_Input" left="170" top="70" width="300" height="50" fontSize="32"/>

    <s:Button id="Populate_Button" left="10" right="10" top="130" height="50" label="Populate"
              click="PopulateButtonClick()"/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;     

            protected var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;
            public var valueToBeRead:String;

            public function get_DB_info(tableName:String):void
            {   
                sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
                sqlConnection.open(File.userDirectory.resolvePath(DB_to_Read.text+".db"));
                var add2db:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                add2db.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                add2db.text = ("SELECT answer FROM "+tableName+" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
                add2db.execute();
                valueToBeRead = add2db.getResult().data.toString();//.valueOf();//.toString();
            }

            protected function PopulateButtonClick():void
            {   
                get_DB_info("Test_Title");  
                Test_Title_Input.text = valueToBeRead;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `add2db.getResult()` the return object is a [`SQLResult`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html). The info there about the [data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html#data) property is very useful. It says that the data property is an `Array` of `Objects` containing your result.

In your case, it looks like your SQL query will return exactly 1 database row, and that row contains only one column: `answer`

So you should therefore be able to populate the text input like this:

```
var firstRow:Object = add2db.getResult().data[0];
valueToBeRead = firstRow["answer"];
// or, instead of storing it in a variable, just assign it to the text input right away
Test_Title_Input.text = firstRow["answer"];
```

Comment: Thank you, both work perfect.  The valueToBeRead is because ultimately Test_Title_Input will not be the only cell being populated.